# H3Error: vite_ssr_import_1 is not defined vue3 and nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, fullcalendar-5

I hope you can help me, I want to integrate fullcalendar into my project, but I have the following problem:

[h3] [unhandled] H3Error: **vite_ssr_import_1** is not defined

[image]

I have done the same from the documentation, but still I have that problem, if someone can help me, I would appreciate it, here is my code:

my sight:

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import "@fullcalendar/core/vdom"; // solves problem with Vite
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue3";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin],
        initialView: "timeGridWeek",
        nowIndicator: true,
        editable: true,
        initialEvents: [{ title: "nice event", start: new Date() }],
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.app {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "performlead",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.18.9",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^5.11.2",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.0.96",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.33.1",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.24.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.21",
    "sass": "^1.54.3",
    "typecheck": "^0.1.2",
    "v-calendar": "^2.4.1",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

documentation link with nuxt:

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/nuxt